# Xamarin.Forms - How To Achieve 45 deg. Angled Background Color

Tags: xamarin, background, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms, how would I achieve the following angled background without using an image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### A 100% `Xamarin.Forms` with no "custom renderer" involved solution:

In the example below, the solid blue portion of the semi-transparent box behind the `Labels` on the screen is a `NControl`, you can also do  gradients, simple animations, etc... but in this case just a solid polygon is being drawn within a semi-transperent rectangle:

[image]

Using `NGraphics` via `NControl` you can do a lot in terms of drawing custom controls in `Xamarin.Forms` without custom renderers. It is not a solution in every use-case, but its clean and works cross-platform (iOS/Android/WinPhone).

```cs
var overlay = new NControlView()
{
    BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black.MultiplyAlpha(.3f),
    DrawingFunction = (canvas, rect) =>
    {
        canvas.FillPath(new PathOp[] {
            new MoveTo (NGraphics.Point.Zero),
            new LineTo ((rect.Width / 3), 0),
            new LineTo ((rect.Width / 3) * 2, rect.Height),
            new LineTo (0, rect.Height),
            new ClosePath ()
        }, Colors.Blue);
    }
};
```

Rendered in `Red` with a heavier alpha setting so you can see the control better:

[image]

This control is embedded in an `AbsoluteLayout` that uses dynamic bounds so even orientation changes are handled cleanly:

```cs
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(overlay, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(overlay, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, 1, 1, 0.3));
```

[image]

- https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics
- https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl

Comment: Nice one ! Really good ! It's possible to bind a onclick event on this polygon ? Thanks for your response

Comment: @ThomasMontagnoni Sure, the control has touch events: https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl/blob/develop/NControlDemo/NControlDemo.FormsApp/Controls/CircularButtonControl.cs

Comment: An update, just for a piece of information: We cannot use this 'NControl' with the .NET Standard 2.0 Xamarin.Forms project. Throws not compatible exception.

Comment: @MeikandaNayanar.I FYI: You can recompile NControl for NetStd2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define a gradient in Xamarin Forms.  Your best bet would be to use an image.  However, you could also try writing a custom renderer that used the underlying platform API to draw a gradient background.

Here is a [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22440/gradient-as-background-color) that discusses using the custom renderer approach.