# Create triangle shape in a corner xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to create a triangle at the corner of a label/frame like the pic below with a number/small text in it.But just a way to draw the corner would be a great start.

How Can you do you do that ?
Any sample anywhere. Many thanks

[image]

Comment: XFShapeView nuget package may help you. Sample code : https://github.com/vincentgury/XFShapeView/blob/master/sample/XFShapeViewSample/XFShapeViewSample/MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: @MilanG thanks for the suggestions. Have you used it before .Can I easily draw a shape in xaml and put a text in it.

Comment: I didn't get chance to use it yet but you should give it a try. Other way is to put an image with triangle at top right corner and on top of it, put a Label to show some text over triangle.

Comment: @developer9969 Take a look at NGraphics / Ncontrol : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949635/xamarin-forms-how-to-achieve-45-deg-angled-background-color/36951593#36951593 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745131/xamarin-forms-absolute-layout-draw-shape-based-on-coordinate/47746000#47746000

Comment: looked into both and but cannot get to build a triangle.Any snippets ?thanks

Comment: In your case, you could use absolute layout and simply put a triangle at the corner of the layout.

Comment: @Shaw how do you draw a triangle in xamarin forms any snippets

Answer (score 4):

Instead Using Plugin for just Triangle you can just use BoxView and rotate it with 135 and give negative margin so half portion will only get visible.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using NControl https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl

```
public class DiagonalControl : NControlView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusBindableProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(int), typeof(DiagonalControl), 8);

    private Xamarin.Forms.Color _backgroundColor;

    public DiagonalControl()
    {
        base.BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent;
    }

    public new Xamarin.Forms.Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _backgroundColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _backgroundColor = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int CornerRadius
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusBindableProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CornerRadiusBindableProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public override void Draw(ICanvas canvas, Rect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas, rect);

        canvas.FillPath(new PathOp[] {
            new MoveTo (0,0),
            new LineTo (rect.Width, rect.Height),
            new LineTo (rect.Width, 0),
            new ClosePath ()
        }, new NGraphics.Color((Xamarin.Forms.Color.White).R, (Xamarin.Forms.Color.White).G, (Xamarin.Forms.Color.White).B));
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML use it like

```
<customviews:DiagonalControl
                            x:FieldModifier="Public"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            WidthRequest="50" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Draw path directly in xaml from Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0
(bump into the same request, and have an update for others)

```
<Path
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    Data="M 0,0 L 36,0 36,36Z"
    Fill="#70a33e"
    Stroke="Gray" />
```

And more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shapes-and-paths/

[image]